# How can I aggregate elements on a flux by group / how to reduce groupwise?

Tags: java, flux, project-reactor

Assume you have a flux of objects with the following structure:

```
class Element {
  String key;
  int count;
}
```

Now imagine those elements flow in a predefined sort order, always in groups of a key, like

```
{ key = "firstKey",  count=123}
{ key = "firstKey",  count=1  }
{ key = "secondKey", count=4  }
{ key = "thirdKey",  count=98 }
{ key = "thirdKey",  count=5  }
 .....
```

What I want to do is create a flux which returns one element for each distinct `key` and summed `count` for each key-group.
So basically like a classic reduce for each group, but using the `reduce` operator does not work, because it only returns a single element and I want to get a flux with one element for each distinct key.

Using `bufferUntil` might work, but has the drawback, that I have to keep a state to check if the `key` has changed in comparison  to the previous one.

Using `groupBy` is an overkill, as I know that each group has come to an end once a new key is found, so I don't want to keep anything cached after that event.

Is such an aggregation possible using `Flux`, without keeping a state outside of the flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently (as of 3.2.5) not possible without keeping track of state yourself. `distinctUntilChanged` could have fit the bill with minimal state but doesn't emit the state, just the values it considered as "distinct" according to said state.

The most minimalistic way of solving this is with `windowUntil` and `compose` + an `AtomicReference` for state-per-subscriber:

```
Flux<Tuple2<T, Integer>> sourceFlux = ...; //assuming key/count represented as `Tuple2`
Flux<Tuple2<T, Integer>> aggregated = sourceFlux.compose(source -> {
    //having this state inside a compose means it will not be shared by multiple subscribers
    AtomicReference<T> last = new AtomicReference<>(null);

    return source
      //use "last seen" state so split into windows, much like a `groupBy` but with earlier closing
      .windowUntil(i -> !i.getT1().equals(last.getAndSet(i.getT1())), true)
      //reduce each window
      .flatMap(window -> window.reduce((i1, i2) -> Tuples.of(i1.getT1(), i1.getT2() + i2.getT2()))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That really worked for me! Thanks for that post.
Please note that in the meantime the "compose" method was renamed. You need to use `transformDeferred` instead.
In my case I have a "Dashboard" object which has an id (stored as UUID) on which I want to group the source flux:

```
Flux<Dashboard> sourceFlux = ... // could be a DB query. The Flux must be sorted according the id.  

sourceFlux.transformDeferred(dashboardFlux -> {
    // this stores the dashboardId's as the Flux publishes. It is used to decide when to open a new window
    // having this state inside a compose means it will not be shared by multiple subscribers
    AtomicReference<UUID> last = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    
    return dashboardFlux
    //use "last seen" state so split into windows, much like a `groupBy` but with earlier closing
        .windowUntil(i -> !i.getDashboardId().equals(last.getAndSet(i.getDashboardId())), true)
        //reduce each window
        .flatMap(window -> window.reduce(... /* reduce one window here */));
})
```